# Node middleware to serve mobile users different HTML Angular files?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, middleware

A website I just created for my company is currently responsive and works very well on mobile, but I'm dealing with an annoying flickering caused by a [module](https://github.com/c0bra/angular-responsive-images) that serves up different image sizes based on viewport, but does so in the HTML itself.

This website will eventually be launched as a native mobile app via Cordova in a few months, but in the meantime we want to dynamically serve a mobile version using node middleware. I want to redirect the index.html to mobile.html, use new configuration and state Angular files, but otherwise continuing using the same Angular controllers/services/factories with new mobile html templates – if this is impossible and I need to duplicate everything, then I will rethink this process.

Here are the relevant portions of my server.js file:

```
    const app               = express();
    let mobile              = false;
    const socialMedia       = express.Router();

    let server              = require('http').createServer(app);

    app.use(function(req, res, next){
      var ua = req.headers['user-agent'];
      if(/^(facebookexternalhit)|(Twitterbot)|(LinkedInBot)|(Pinterest)|(Slackbot-LinkExpanding)/gi.test(ua)){
         socialMedia(req, res, next);
      }
      else if(/Mobi/i.test(ua)){
        mobile = true;
      } else {
        next();
      }
    });

    // Require routes
    let postRoutes          = require('./server/routes/postRoutes');
    let categoryRoutes      = require('./server/routes/categoryRoutes');
    let pageRoutes          = require('./server/routes/pageRoutes');

    // Use routes
    app.use(postRoutes);
    app.use(categoryRoutes);
    app.use(pageRoutes);

    // Set up app and body parser
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client')));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use('*', function(req, res){
      if (mobile) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/mobile.index.html');
      } else {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/desktop.index.html');
      }
    });

    // Start server
    server.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, function(){
      console.log('Express server listening on port %d', this.address().port);
    });
```

Even when mobile is set to false, it sends the mobile.index.html file, and when I try to change the user agent via Chrome dev tools, nothing loads at all, it just continuously tries to load but nothing is ever rendered.

Is this impossible? I can't find a lot out there on the best way to handle this kind of situation.

Comment: Hi, can you try to put all your routes block:

`app.use(postRoutes); app.use(categoryRoutes); app.use(pageRoutes);`
after this block  `app.use('*', function(req, res){...` ?